# Setting dash length when plotting arrow

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib its easy to plot a line with a customised dash style using

```
plt.plot([0, 5], [0, 5], dashes=(20.0, 20.0))
plt.show()
```

or

```
lines = plt.plot([0, 5], [0, 5])
lines[0].set_dashes((20.0, 20.0))
plt.show()
```

and while its possible to plot arrows with a dashed style

```
plt.arrow(0, 0, 5, 5, linestyle='dashed')
plt.show()
```

I can't seem to figure out how to plot arrows with a custom dash style

```
arrow = plt.arrow(0, 0, 5, 5)
?
plt.show()
```

as using the plot function's `dashes` parameter gives

```
AttributeError: 'FancyArrow' object has no attribute 'set_dashes'
```

and as the error mentions the returned `FancyArrow` has no `set_dashes()` method. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I don't think it possible as the `Arrow` class only supports `'solid' | 'dashed' | 'dashdot' | 'dotted'` four different linestyles. In order to be able to use a customized dash style, the object must have `._dashSeq` property, which `Arrow` lacks. Therefore I can see the reason why `.set_dashes`.

That being said, currently even though the `.set_linestyle` method is provided for `Arrow`, you can't, say, set to anything other than the 4 styles listed above. That means things such as `.set_linestyle('-')` is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a (offset, onoffseq),

> where onoffseq is an even length tuple of on and off ink in points.

See [set_linestyle](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_linestyle).

For example, `ax.arrow(0, 0, 3, 3, linestyle=(5, (3,6)))` creates a dashed arrow with the on ink relatively doubled the length of the off ink; and with `ax.arrow(0, 0, 3, 3, linestyle=(5, (3,9)))`, the on ink tripled the length of the off ink reltively.

Also, the `offset` argument seems not to have any effect in setting an arrow's `linestyle`, at least in 3.0.3, the `matplotlib` version that I was using.

Comment: Just checked that setting ls=(5,(3,6)) also works for modifying arrowstyle in ax.annotate(), wonderful!